# How to make .exe file smaller and faster with pyinstaller (or any other tool)?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I recently made a small desktop app with Tkinter and created a `.exe` file with pyinstaller (`pyinstaller --onefile -w <file-name>`) and had to change some things I was doing in the underlying code to make the `.exe` file smaller.

At the beginning I was using OpenCV to get some frame information from videos (an overkill, I know), which made the `.exe` file 400 MB in size, mostly because of the use of pandas. So I changed that to `python-ffmpeg`. This changed a lot and made the file 16MB. But this is still too big compared to other big program `exe` files, and takes a couple of seconds to start. I'm working with a conda environment that I created only with Python, and other packages/modules I installed in it are XlsxWriter and docx.

Comment: In general, this is completely unavoidable. `pyinstaller` isn't just packaging your program itself, it also packages the Python runtime into the same executable (which then needs to be unpacked into a temporary directory before execution). You'll never get a pyinstaller-packaged program to be as small as (or to have startup time comparable with) an executable with the same functionality implemented with the same algorithms written in a language with minimal runtime amenable to compile-time optimizations.

Comment: So every executable created from a Python script will have this problem irrespective of what package was used to create it?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the file size for `pyinstaller` by creating the build in a separate virtual environment.

Execute `python -m venv demo_env` in your cmd to create a new virtual environment.

After that, install all the packages you need for your script, including `pyinstaller`.

Once you installed everything again, build the exe as before.

Comment: If everything is working correctly, this shouldn't have any effect -- pyinstaller doesn't just bundle every accessible library; instead, it walks the dependency tree and only includes the ones a project actually imports. The approach suggested here can help if something you depend on has optional dependencies it will import if available and ignore if not; but that's a relatively rare circumstance.

Comment: This is what I did. I created the conda environment initially only with Python and then added only the modules/ packages I needed. However, this reduced the size only about 2 MB.

Comment: So it *did reduce the size*

Comment: It reduced the size but it's still 16 MB. This is far from being a solution to the problem. If I was actually needing, for example, OpenCV, then the executable would be 400MB even with a dedicated environment.

Comment: I did the steps and don't reduce the size (still 85 MB)... Why?

Comment: @PedroAntônio That's because this method doesn't really work to reduce the file size too much; only a few megabytes. I'm still to find a way to actually accomplish it. As you can see, this question hasn't really gotten the answer we need.